# Inconsistency with Large Number Subtraction

Tags: c++, largenumber, integer-arithmetic

I'm relatively new to C++, and I'm attempting to create a set of arithmetic functions that are able to handle large numbers, using a struct called `biggie` that handles the numbers like a string. I'm currently having difficulty with the subtract function.

When I run try subtracting with small numbers, it works perfectly fine. When I attempt to scale up, it works fine the first time I call the function.

The second time I call it with large numbers, in another function that will later find the GCD of two large numbers, the answer changes with different runtimes, just slightly. Sometimes, it is the exactly same output as the first. Other times, it is wrong in only 3 digits, and the rest is fine.

This is my code from the subtract function:

```
biggie subtract (biggie a, biggie subtractor) {
    biggie difference;
    string aCopy = a.value;

    int digitDifference = 0;

    for (int i = aCopy.length(); i >= 0; i--) {
        digitDifference = strToInt(aCopy[i]) - strToInt (subtractor.value[i]);

        if (digitDifference < 0) {
            aCopy[i - 1] -= 1;
            digitDifference += 10;
        }

        difference.value += intToStr(digitDifference);
    }

    return difference;
}
```

And this is the code in my `int main()`:

```
biggie a;
a.value = "29345983548974568765879456985698642934598354897456876587945698567986459867895439865798654897568973459806509534897546874539874569845690852598678954398652934598329345983548974568765879456985679864986789543986579865489756897345980650953489754687453987456984569085254897456876587945698567986459867895439865798654897568973459806509534897546874539874569845690852798654897568973459806509534975468745398745698456908522934598354897456876587945698567986459867895439865798654897568973459806509534897546874539874569845690852";

biggie b;
b.value = "293459835489745687658794569856986429345983548974568765879456911111153489754687453987456984569085254897456876222225698567986459867895439865798654897568973459806509534897546874539874569845690852798651111168973459806509534975468745398745698456908522934598354897456876587945698567986459867895439865798654897568973459806509534897546874539874569845690852";

cout << "a: " << a.value << endl;
cout << "b: " << b.value << endl;
cout << "diff: " << (subtract(a, b)).value << endl;

biggie gcf = gcd(a, b);
```

Here is my `gcd` function:

```
biggie gcd (biggie a, biggie b) {
    cout << endl;
    cout << "a: " << a.value << endl;
    cout << "b: " << b.value << endl;
    cout << "diff: " << (subtract(a, b)).value;
    return (subtract(a, b));
}
```

Here was the output I got once, when I run the program (everything is perfect except digits 162 to 164, which are different).

```
a: 29345983548974568765879456985698642934598354897456876587945698567986459867895439865798654897568973459806509534897546874539874569845690852598678954398652934598329345983548974568765879456985679864986789543986579865489756897345980650953489754687453987456984569085254897456876587945698567986459867895439865798654897568973459806509534897546874539874569845690852798654897568973459806509534975468745398745698456908522934598354897456876587945698567986459867895439865798654897568973459806509534897546874539874569845690852
b: 293459835489745687658794569856986429345983548974568765879456911111153489754687453987456984569085254897456876222225698567986459867895439865798654897568973459806509534897546874539874569845690852798651111168973459806509534975468745398745698456908522934598354897456876587945698567986459867895439865798654897568973459806509534897546874539874569845690852
diff: 191013225540743444660078221856942595327491518824156154841295494507920769420781195934078007415265514746382795296725955236558257111156901806817869021100000300281988654648450355571495534474845762360522388515575714067347551318851969118525074113760326683276593397094179939610669980991987011160199799330883848833298072487612158549561427422487741178249739429387671688555714646431881066874165038582214771077947621912806007974406604465925076449662429801117865470000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

a: 29345983548974568765879456985698642934598354897456876587945698567986459867895439865798654897568973459806509534897546874539874569845690852598678954398652934598329345983548974568765879456985679864986789543986579865489756897345980650953489754687453987456984569085254897456876587945698567986459867895439865798654897568973459806509534897546874539874569845690852798654897568973459806509534975468745398745698456908522934598354897456876587945698567986459867895439865798654897568973459806509534897546874539874569845690852
b: 293459835489745687658794569856986429345983548974568765879456911111153489754687453987456984569085254897456876222225698567986459867895439865798654897568973459806509534897546874539874569845690852798651111168973459806509534975468745398745698456908522934598354897456876587945698567986459867895439865798654897568973459806509534897546874539874569845690852
diff: 191013225540743444660078221856942595327491518824156154841295494507920769420781195934078007415265514746382795296725955236558257111156901806817869021100000300281985724648450355571495534474845762360522388515575714067347551318851969118525074113760326683276593397094179939610669980991987011160199799330883848833298072487612158549561427422487741178249739429387671688555714646431881066874165038582214771077947621912806007974406604465925076449662429801117865470000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.085 s
Press ENTER to continue.
```

I'm also using OSX Yosemite and running the program on CodeBlocks, if that changes anything.

EDIT: To clarify, `biggie` is a struct that handles big numbers. `biggie.value` would be a string that contains a large number. The `strToInt()` and `intToStr()` are functions that do exactly as the name implies using the `<sstream>`library. Hope this helps.

Comment: What's `biggie`?

Comment: Why not just use something like [gmp](https://gmplib.org)? It's likely to be both more correct and faster.

Comment: Sorry, `biggie` is a struct that I'm using for handling the large numbers. `biggie.value` would be a string that contains a large numbers. I should clarified this in my post.

Comment: @JesperJuhl It's a final project for school. I'm fairly sure I have to write this myself.

Comment: Have you considered using a debugger?

Comment: "I'm fairly sure I have to write this myself "       Then that is what you should do...And read the book regarding number data types and their useage

Comment: Also don't forget to cite this web page when you turn in your assignment as a source of assistance. Because you aren't really writing it "yourself" any more.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is a school project, I'll provide some clues and no direct answers.

You don't show the `operator[]` for `biggie`.  This could be a problem; consider what happens when `a` is longer than `subtractor`.

Try this test case:  284 - 86.

Is left-to-right the best way to go about doing a subtraction?